# Recursion with C

Tags: c, recursion

I have the code below to reverse a string recursively, it works when I print the chars after the recursion is finished, but I can not figure out how to assemble the reverse chars into a string and return them reversed to the caller. Anyone have an idea? I don't want to add another parameter to accumulate chars, just this way, this is not homework, I am brushing up on small things since I will be graduating in a year and need to do well on interviews.

```
char* reversestring5(char* s)
{

    int i = 0;
    //Not at null terminator
    if(*s!=0)
    {

        //advance the pointer
        reversestring5(s+1);
        printf("%c\n",*s);
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like an infinite loop.

Comment: You'll need to revise your stopping condition, as C strings generally do not start with a null terminator like they end with.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo The stopping condition is fine

Comment: You're not returning type char

Comment: Where do you want to save the reversed string? Do you know in advance how long the string is?

Comment: Sorry, the i was a left over from an idea I tried before. This works, but it just prints, I want to assemble a string when the chars on the stack are popped and return it, I think this is possible?

Comment: Note that your code doesn't assign anything to the string, so the string is not altered in any way.  That alone means it cannot possibly achieve the desired effect, even though it prints out the characters in the string in reverse order.

Comment: Yes, I understand this, maybe I wasn't clear, that is what I want to do but I can't figured it out without adding another parameter (tail recursion?).

Comment: Why on earth would one use recursion to do this ? This approach will overflow the stack for a long enough char. This as bad as using a fixed length buffer with no check on the length of the input string. And this uses one stack frame per char !? This seems a really flawed design.

Comment: Yes it is, I was trying to see if it could be done. I've been preparing to interview something I hate and I get these kinds of ridiculous questions all the time so I'm trying to prepare for it.

Comment: "It looks like an infinite loop." -- Eh? No. "You'll need to revise your stopping condition, as C strings generally do not start with" -- Eh? No. That comment would make sense if it were a starting condition.

Comment: "I don't want to add another parameter to accumulate chars" -- Well, you have to accumulate them *somewhere*. See my answer, which satisfies your requirements, does not alter the original string, is O(n), doesn't use globals, avoids the problems and mistakes of the other answers ... it can of course overflow the stack, but that's a given for recursion.

Answer (score 5):

With a recursive function, it's usually easiest to first figure out how to solve a trivial case (e.g. reversing a string with just a pair of characters) and then see how one might divide up the the problem into simple operations culminating with the trivial case.  For example one might do this:

This is the actual recursive function:

```
char *revrecurse(char *front, char *back)
{
    if (front < back) {
        char temp = *front;
        *front = *back;
        *back = temp;
        revrecurse(front+1, back-1);
    }
    return front;
}
```

This part just uses the recursive function:

```
char *reverse(char *str)
{
    return revrecurse(str, &str[strlen(str)-1]);
}
```

Note that this assumes that the pointer is valid and that it points to a `NUL`-terminated string.

If you're going to actually reverse the characters, you can either provide a pair of pointers and recursively swap letters (which is what this routine does) or copy the characters one at a time into yet another space.  That's essentially what your original code is doing; copying each character at a time to `stdout` which is a global structure that is not explicitly passed but is being used by your routine.  The analog to that approach, but using pointers might look like this:

```
#define MAXSTRINGLEN 200

char revbuf[MAXSTRINGLEN];
char *refptr = revbuf;

char *revstring(char *s)
{
    if (*s != 0)
    {
        revstring(s+1);
        *refptr++ = *s;    /* copy non-NUL characters */
    } else {
        *refptr++ = '\0';  /* copy NUL character */
    }
    return revbuf;
}
```

In this minor modification to your original code, you can now see the reliance of this approach on global variables `revbuf` and `refptr` which were hidden inside `stdout` in your original code.  Obviously this is not even close to optimized -- it's intended solely for explanatory purposes.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote:  is there something I might improve?

Comment: Not my down-vote.  You could make the helper function `static` so that it won't be used outside (it isn't the documented interface).

Comment: @Edward the use of strlen bugs me. I hope there is a better way.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: good comment; it's worthwhile to narrow the interface where practical.

Comment: @ma08: If you have a version which doesn't use `strlen` or the equivalent, it could be useful alternative answer.

Comment: I get this, but I wanted to maintain the signature of passing in the original string. What I don't understand with mine is why can the printf print the chars in reverse but when I try to assemble them in a new string after the recurse call and return the new string it is not reversed?

Comment: The fact that you're `printing` doesn't change the `string buffer`.

Comment: @DixonSteel because you are actually putting the characters where they originally were. The recursive call has no effect on the character pointed in the function. So you are getting the same string

Comment: @ma08: +1. Still sure about the iterable version?

Comment: @jweyrich still sure about exactly what?

Comment: @ma08: about your assumption I mentioned earlier in my answer's comments.

Comment: @jweyrich not so sure I guess. But it doesn't change the point of my argument against your answer. It wasn't what he wanted

Comment: (e.g. reversing a string with just a pair of characters): the trully trivial case would be reversing a string with 0 or 1 elements. Then there is nothing to do :)

Comment: @DixonSteel: I've revised my answer to explain how your original code worked and to provide similar code which illustrates the point.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for, not crazy about the globals but I see the point.I don't get thought how does my original one put them back but printing them does not?

Comment: @DixonSteel "What I don't understand with mine is why can the printf print the chars in reverse but when I try to assemble them in a new string after the recurse call and return the new string it is not reversed?" -- Since you didn't post any code to do that, we can't tell you what's wrong with it. But how are you going to assemble the reversed chars into a string when you haven't saved them anywhere, you've only printed them?

Comment: `revstring` can only be called once ... any subsequent call is UB.

Comment: @JimBalter: yes, of course.  It's purely a minimal illustrative example, not production code.

Comment: I didn't say anything about production code. The problem is, it can't be fixed ... or if it can, you haven't offered any inkling as to how.

Answer (score 2):

"Reversing a string recursively" is a very vague statement of a problem, which allows for many completely different solutions.

Note that a "reasonable" solution should avoid making excessive passes over the string. Any solution that begins with `strlen` is not really a reasonable one. It is recursive for the sake of being recursive and nothing more. If one resorts to making an additional pass over the string, one no longer really needs a recursive solution at all. In other words, any solution that begins with `strlen` is not really satisfactory.

So, let's look for a more sensible single-pass recursive solution. And you almost got it already.

Your code already taught you that the reverse sequence of characters is obtained on the backtracking phase of recursion. That's exactly where you placed your `printf`. So, the "straightforward" approach would be to take these reversed characters, and instead of `printf`-ing them just write them back into the original string starting from the beginning of the string. A naive attempt to do this might look as follows

```
void reversestring_impl(char* s, char **dst)
{
  if (*s != '\0')
  {
    reversestring_impl(s + 1, dst);
    *(*dst)++ = *s;
  }
}

void reversestring5(char* s)
{
  char *dst = s;
  reversestring_impl(s, &dst);
}
```

Note that this implementation uses an additional parameter `dst`, which carries the destination location for writing the next output character. That destination location remains unchanged on the forward pass of the recursion, and gets incremented as we write output characters on the backtracking pass of the recursion.

However, the above code will not work properly, since we are working "in place", i.e. using the same string as input and output at the same time. The beginning of the string will get overwritten prematurely. This will destroy character information that will be needed on later backtracking steps. In order to work around this issue each nested level of recursion should save its current character locally before the recursive call and use the saved copy after the recursive call

```
void reversestring_impl(char* s, char **dst)
{
  if (*s != '\0')
  {
    char c = *s;
    reversestring_impl(s + 1, dst);
    *(*dst)++ = c;
  }
}

void reversestring5(char* s)
{
  char *dst = s;
  reversestring_impl(s, &dst);
}

int main()
{
  char str[] = "123456789";

  reversestring5(str);

  printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

The above works as intended.

Comment: You might want to make `reversestring_impl` return `void` and simply return `s` from within `reversestring5`.  Also, is there a reason you're not simply calling `reversestring_impl(s, &s)` from within `reversestring5`?

Comment: @Edward: Well, I just wanted to keep it as close as possible to the OP's version so that the OP would be able to easily recognize the similarities. The OP had `return s` there, so I kept it. Yes, of course, it is not necessary to `return s` from anywhere (and I'm not using the return value in `main`). As for using `&s` in `impl`.. yes, that will definitely work. But, firstly, I just had an intuitive feeling that an extra variable might make it more readable to a beginner. And, secondly, I prefer to keep the original parameter values unchanged.

Comment: A function that reverses a string *in place* should be declared void. Yours is a clever solution for that sort of function, but nothing was said about that in the problem statement, which says "assemble the reverse chars into a string and return them reversed to the caller". My answer gives a solution that does just that.

Comment: @Jim Balter: I don't see why it should be declared `void`. It is a widely used implementation pattern in C language, when a function returns the same pointer as the one passed to it as input. `strcpy` is a classic example of that. It is done to simplify function chaining.

Comment: For the same reason that qsort is declared void. When it's common to have versions of a function that are both in situ and not because of the efficiency of the former, it's not good interface design for the in situ version to return the result. As for strcpy, it was written in the dark ages and every experienced C programmer knows that it should have returned the address of the terminating NUL of the target, which would have been useful.

Comment: I agree with the void, I think the char* is there to test knowledge, I got this from one of those company questions from a friend where his company asks this.

Comment: @Dixon Steel: No problem, let's switch everything to `void`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really can't use a helper function and you really can't modify the interface to the function and you really must use recursion, you could do this, horrible though it is:

```
char *str_reverse(char *str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    if (len > 1)
    {
        char c0 = str[0];
        char c1 = str[len-1];
        str[len-1] = '\0';
        (void)str_reverse(str+1);
        str[0] = c1;
        str[len-1] = c0;
    }
    return str;
}
```

This captures the first and last characters in the string (you could survive without capturing the first), then shortens the string, calls the function on the shortened string, then reinstates the swapped first and last characters.  The return value is really of no help; I only kept it to keep the interface unchanged.  This is clearest when the recursive call ignores the return value.

Note that this is gruesome for performance because it evaluates `strlen()` (N/2) times, rather than just once.  Given a gigabyte string to reverse, that matters.

I can't think of a good way to write the code without using `strlen()` or its equivalent.  To reverse the string in situ, you have to know where the end is somehow.  Since the interface you stipulate does not include the information on where the end is, you have to find the end in the function, somehow.  I don't regard `strchr(str, '\0')` as significantly different from `strlen(str)`, for instance.

If you change the interface to:

```
void mem_reverse_in_situ(char *start, char *end)
{
    if (start < end)
    {
        char c0 = *start;
        *start = *end;
        *end = c0;
        mem_reverse_in_situ(start+1, end-1);
    }
}
```

Then the reversal code avoids all issues of string length (or memory length) — requiring the calling code to deal with it.  The function simply swaps the ends and calls itself on the middle segment.  You'd not write this as a recursive function, though; you'd use an iterative solution:

```
void mem_reverse_in_situ(char *start, char *end)
{
    while (start < end)
    {
        char c0 = *start;
        *start++ = *end;
        *end-- = c0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried something like this but could not get it. I would never do anything like the first one, but this was just a personnel challenge to maintain the signature and I failed at it.

Comment: Why not use the recursive one as opposed to the iterative one?

Comment: You'd not use the recursive `mem_reverse_in_situ()` because it uses much more stack space than the iterative one.  There will be an upper limit on the size of string you can reverse, whereas the iterative version uses fixed amount of space regardless of the length of the string being reversed. Also, repeatedly calling the function will take longer than iterating will, so the iterative solution is more efficient (but there's a modest chance that the compiler might spot the tail recursion and convert the code to the iterative solution anyway).

Comment: "I can't think of a good way to write the code without using strlen() or its equivalent." -- See AndreyT's answer for reversing the string in place, and mine for doing what the OP asked for and returning a reversal of the string ... without intermediate modifying of the string, which is UB if the string isn't writable. reverse_string *should* take a `const char*` argument, and mine does.

Comment: @JimBalter: there was zero call for a non-modifiable argument in the question, so an answer which provides workable code that modifies in situ is certainly within the remit of the question.  If you want to handle a constant string argument, that's fine; it is a different question, and a harder question (not a lot harder, but harder).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I addressed "I can't think of a good way" -- as I said, AndreyT provides one. I don't consider the ability to handle arguments that are string literals, values in argv, or otherwise unwritable to be "a different question" but I know that it's pointless to argue with people who make such claims. As for "not a lot harder", there's a big gap between knowing how to solve a problem and not knowing how, regardless of the difficulty of implementation.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* reversestring5(char* s){
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    char last[2] = {*s};
    return (len > 1) ? strcat(memmove(s, reversestring5(s+1), len), last) : s;
}
```

Comment: I even tried something like this, but failed. I would think this would run slow, but this and the other two are what I wanted to do. I'm not sure which one is the answer to mark, since 3 of them fit.

Comment: @DixonSteel I'd say none of them really fits because they utilize `strlen` which surely just performs a loop until it reaches the `0`. Why not then loop all the way through `1.5` times in total and seal the deal? I couldn't find a solution that fits your criteria, and also doesn't cheat by using further functions, which is why I didn't provide any.

Comment: @DixonSteel See my answer, which avoids the mentioned problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question, and the answer involves a technique that apparently few people are familiar with, judging by the other answers. This does the job ... it recursively converts the string into a linked list (kept on the stack, so it's quite efficient) that represents the reversal of the string. It then converts the linked list back into a string (which it does iteratively, but the problem statement doesn't say it can't). There's a complaint in the comments that this is "overkill", but *any* recursive solution will be overkill ... recursion is simply not a good way to process an array in reverse. But note that there is a whole set of problems that this approach can be applied to where one generates values on the fly rather than having them already available in an array, and then they are to be processed in reverse. Since the OP is interested in developing or brushing up on skills, this answer provides extra value ... and because this technique of creating a linked list on the stack and then consuming the linked list in the termination condition (as it must be, before the memory of the linked list goes out of scope) is apparently not well known. An example is backtrack algorithms such as for the Eight Queens problem.

In response to complaints that this isn't "pure recursive" because of the iterative copy of the list to the string buffer, I've updated it to do it both ways:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Cnode Cnode;
struct Cnode
{
    char c;
    const Cnode* next;
};

static void list_to_string(char* s, const Cnode* np)
{
#ifdef ALL_RECURSIVE
    if (np)
    {
        *s = np->c;
        list_to_string(s+1, np->next);
    }
    else
        *s = '\0';
#else
    for (; np; np = np->next)
        *s++ = np->c;
    *s = '\0';
#endif
}

static char* reverse_string_recursive(const char* s, size_t len, const Cnode* np)
{
    if (*s)
    {
        Cnode cn = { *s, np };
        return reverse_string_recursive(s+1, len+1, &cn);
    }

    char* rs = malloc(len+1);
    if (rs)
        list_to_string(rs, np);
    return rs;
}

char* reverse_string(const char* s)
{
    return reverse_string_recursive(s, 0, NULL);
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        const char* rs = reverse_string(argv[1]);
        printf("%s\n", rs? rs : "[malloc failed in reverse_string]");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now that's using a six-barrel handheld hellfire rocket launcher to kill a mosquito.

Comment: @Quentin No, it's a simple straightforward solution to the given problem, and a technique that can be used for similar problems. Of course there are much easier ways to reverse a string, but the requirement here is explicitly to use recursion. This solution uses no globals, no repeated strlens/strcats/memmoves ... it's O(N). It directly addresses "I can not figure out how to assemble the reverse chars into a string and return them reversed to the caller." And it doesn't change the original string, which surely isn't acceptable.

Comment: There's no reason to use strlen, since we are _already_ walking the string. But yeah, building and collapsing a linked list seems overkill to me. I was thinking about memory consumption, but in fact it's all in the stack so who cares.

Comment: @Quentin "seems overkill to me" -- then post your alternative answer with the given characteristics ... there really isn't one.

Comment: @Quentin "There's no reason to use strlen, since we are already walking the string." -- Yeah, well, tell that to the people who used it in their answers.

Comment: It's late here and I'm in no condition to write code, so honestly I don't have one at hand. But I find it weird to have no choice but use a linked list following the call stack, and used _exactly_ like it (build in one direction, consumed in  the other one). If it's actually the case I'll stand corrected. Also, you'd need to recursify this `for` loop for this answer to be genuinely "recursive". **Edit:** I'm in no way comparing with the other answers (for which my statement stands).

Comment: @Quentin What you find weird isn't relevant ... I find it intuitively obvious. " Also, you'd need to recursify this for loop for this answer to be genuinely "recursive"." -- No, I don't, and that *would* be overkill. Note that malloc also contains loops in its code ... that simply isn't relevant.

Comment: "build in one direction, consumed in the other one" -- that's reversal in a nutshell. "If it's actually the case I'll stand corrected." -- You haven't offered any possible alternative. There are really only two choices ... consume in the same direction as built, or the opposite.

Comment: Finally, note my usage in main, of reversing a command line argument. With the exception of Edward's second solution that uses an external buffer (of limited size), all of the other answers have undefined behavior for that usage.

Comment: +1 from me.  The only slight change I'd make would be to increment `s` within the recursive call rather than in the construction of `cn`, but that's solely to emphasize what's changing in the recursion.  Also, I don't think that it's "not well known" so much as "infrequently optimal" but it's a good technique to know.

Comment: @Edward Good suggestion ... see edit. I stick by "not well known", and I think it's always optimal for the use case I mentioned, where one recursively generates a set of results to be processed when the recursion terminates, as in backtracking. Such cases are themselves "infrequent" but that is true of the use cases for many programming techniques.

Comment: It's truly "weird" to call this overkill ... take away `main`, the outer wrapper function, and the loop to convert the linked list to a string (which could be encapsulated in another function) and there's nothing to it but pure recursion.

Comment: Well, pure recursion plus an iteration at the end.  See AndreyT's answer for something that's perhaps a little more "pure" in that regard.

Comment: @Edward I said "take away ... the loop to convert the linked list to a string". AndreyT's answer, like so many here, overwrites the original string, which I consider just wrong -- a function that does that should return void. If one insists on total absence of iteration (and why?), then the function of "encapsulated in another function" can be implemented recursively.

Comment: @Edward "Well, pure recursion plus an iteration at the end" -- my point was about the part that *is* pure, which converts a string into a linked list representing the reversed string. Since that is the heart of the algorithm, and it's quite simple, it's odd to call it overkill, when no one is calling it overkill to call strlen, strcat, and memmove at every level, for instance.

Comment: @Edward I've now included a version with no "iteration at the end".

Comment: And I do hope that no one considers long, complete answers to questions at SO to be "overkill" ... they should instead be encouraged (and certainly not downvoted).

Comment: I haven't fully read this, but this is great IMO. Yes I want to brush up I graduate soon and I am sick of being torn apart in interviews. One thing, I read where most compilers now optimize recursion and its not that bad for efficiently but I don't know it that is true?

Comment: "consuming the linked list in the termination condition" This was my original thought and I know at one time Ive done this but could not remember how and googl-ing it is hard because I don't know what to search for.

Comment: @DixonSteel "this is great IMO" -- well, you could upvote it (or even accept it if you choose). Only certain kinds of recursion can be optimized (here, list_to_string can be but reverse_string_recursive can't) ... google "tail recursion optimization".

Answer (score 1):

Here's a "there and back again" [Note 1] in-place reverse which:

- doesn't use `strlen()` and doesn't need to know how long the string is in advance; and
- has a maximum recursion depth of half of the string length.

It also never backs up an iterator, so if it were written in C++, it could use a forward iterator. However, that feature is less interesting because it keeps iterators on the stack and requires that you can consistently iterate forward from an iterator, so it can't use input iterators. Still, it does mean that it can be used to in-place reverse values in a singly-linked list, which is possibly slightly interesting.

```
static void swap(char* lo, char* hi) {
  char tmp = *hi;
  *hi = *lo;
  *lo = tmp;
}

static char* step(char* tortoise, char* hare) {
  if (hare[0]) return tortoise;
  if (hare[1]) return tortoise + 1;
  hare = step(tortoise + 1, hare + 2);
  swap(tortoise, hare);
  return hare + 1;
}

void reverse_in_place(char* str) { step(str, str); }
```

---

Note 1: The "there and back again" pattern comes from a paper by Olivier Danvy and Mayer Goldberg, which makes for fun reading. The paper still seems to be online at ftp://ftp.daimi.au.dk/pub/BRICS/pub/RS/05/3/BRICS-RS-05-3.pdf

Comment: I'll check out the paper. I'm glad I asked this question, its got me thinking about more recursive things.